# SQL query using like vs group by aggregation function - performance

Tags: mysql, performance

I am trying to get the first `SRC` entry  for each application (`app_id`).

Image table has 2 columns (`app_id`, `src`).

Two solutions:
 - Using `MIN`. 
 - Using `LIKE` .

I have the following two queries and am wondering which performs faster or are they both equivalent?

Should I use different metrics or functions?

### Queries

**MIN with GROUP BY**

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT app_id,
       min(src)
FROM image
GROUP BY app_id ;
```

**LIKE**

```
EXPLAIN
SELECT app_id,
       i.src
FROM image i
WHERE i.src LIKE '%.0.jpg';
```

### **Results:**

```
mysql> EXPLAIN select app_id, min(src) from image group by app_id limit   100000;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-----------------------------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key                         | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-----------------------------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | image | index | NULL          | FK_x2mlprm4ootu8u253f7sd9rs | 768     | NULL | 52532 | Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-----------------------------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> EXPLAIN select app_id, i.src from image i where i.src like '%.0.jpg' limit 100000;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-----------------------------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key                         | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-----------------------------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | i     | index | NULL          | FK_x2mlprm4ootu8u253f7sd9rs | 768     | NULL | 52532 | Using where; Using index |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+-----------------------------+---------+------+-------+--------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

### Clarifications

- The data stored and structure is such that the two queries produce equivalent results.
- The data is stored (from the application logic) in such a way that `min(src)` will always return the same as `LIKE '%.0.jpg'`
- `.0.jpg` is the smallest src per app there can be, as everything preceding `.0.jpg` is identical for entries belonging to same `app`.
- Please assume (and state when) that columns will/can be indexed in the best possible way. Changes can be made to the table.

Comment: You do probably need to fill in more data in the db to get representative results...

Comment: Your second query does not contain `GROUP BY`  clause. More, those two queries logically are just different. How can they be compared?

Comment: @Alma Problems can be solved in different ways and people compare them to find the fastest solution. In the case above is speed comparable? Or is `like` faster than `group by` + min ?

Comment: I believe the first one should be more efficient as long as you have an index on app_id. I don't think a hash index on src would be used in a partial text search. Full text indexes might, if you can use MATCH instead of LIKE.

Comment: if src and app_ID are indexed than the min should be volumes faster as it will not have to do a string compare.

Comment: @maythesource.com well, problem _can be solved_ with different ways, but in order to solve __same__ problem, all ways must provide __same__ result (which is the solution for the problem). Obviously, that your two queries won't result in same row sets.

Comment: @Alma Do Actually, they do result in the `same` result. Xmm, removing the limit by.

Comment: Then you should provide data logic & minimal data set. Because if they actually have same result, that's because of specific conditions on your data.

Comment: The specific data for the specific DB/APP gaurantee that only one src with `.0.jpg` will exist per app.

Comment: You should add that point into the question, it's important restriction

Comment: But is that the only src for an app, or will there never be a src with a smaller value for each app?

Comment: @Alma Do Added Clarifications.

Comment: As @xQbert says, with an index covering app_id and src (in that order) the first will be massively faster. The query can run directly from the indexes. With the 2nd query no conventional index will help due to the leading wildcard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `GROUP BY` query should be the fastest one, since it is based mainly on an index while the `LIKE` query is using the index only partially (as indicated by the `EXPLAIN`, where it says `Using where; Using index`), and surely not for the `i.src like '%.0.jpg'` part.

In the [MySQL Reference Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-indexes.html) it is reported the following:

> The index also can be used for LIKE comparisons if the argument to
>   LIKE is a constant string that does not start with a wildcard
>   character. For example, the following SELECT statements use indexes:
>
> ```
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE key_col LIKE 'Patrick%';
> SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE key_col LIKE 'Pat%_ck%';
> ```

Since in your case the argument starts with a wildcard, it won't use the index, therefore the query should be slower.